# Selenium NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, webdriverwait

I am struggling with Selenium

for the url: https://pubchem.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/compound/2078

I am trying to click the button Download, but it doesn't find the element.

My code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from ipykernel import kernelapp as app
import time

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
driver_path = 'C:\\Users\\Idener\\Downloads\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(driver_path, options=options)
url = f"https://pubchem.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/compound/2078"
driver.get(url)
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='"'page-download-btn'"']").click()
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ob70n.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing a delay.
Element should clicked only when it is completely rendered and ready to accept a click event. `WebDriverWait` `expected_conditions` explicit waits should be used for that.
Also, no need to add `f` before URL value and `'"'` instead of `'` in XPath expression.
The following code will work for you:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from ipykernel import kernelapp as app
import time

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
driver_path = 'C:\\Users\\Idener\\Downloads\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(driver_path, options=options)
url = "https://pubchem.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/compound/2078"
driver.get(url)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "page-download-btn"))).click()
```

Comment: Should update options one.

Comment: @ArundeepChohan what do you mean?

Comment: In case the question you asked is resolved please accept it. Each question here should be limited to 1 specific point, so if you have a new question - please ask it in a new, separate question. https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: Sorry! I didn't know the protocol! I posted a new question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74107903/selenium-nosuchelementexception-message-no-such-element   Thank you

Comment: I see, it's totally OK.

Answer (score 1):

Your XPath is not valid. You don't need so much quotes

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='page-download-btn']").click()
```